# Proving I can reach any unit vector

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, vectors

I have a vector $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\0\\0\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\phi}\end{bmatrix}$$ and two matrices:$$\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi}&0&0&0\\0&e^{i\phi}&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&0&-e^{i\phi}&0\\0&\cos(\theta)&0&-e^{i\phi}\sin( \theta )\\e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)&0&\cos(\theta)&0\\0&e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)&0&\cos (\theta )\end{bmatrix}$$ Where  $\theta$ and $\phi$ vary depending on the beamsplitter/phaseshifter you're using.
How would I go about proving that I could reach any unit vector? I would prefer just a hint, as I'd like to figure it out myself.

Notes on meaning: by "reach any unit vector" I mean that, by applying a combination of matrices to the original vector state, I can get as a result any unit vector in $\mathbb{C}^4$. I basically (as 123 helped me realize) want to prove that for fixed $\theta,\phi$ some combination of $A$ and $B$ (times your vector) will get you all the vectors in $\mathbb{C}^4$. I'm thinking in the context of applying different operations to a photon. I can apply these operations in any order, but I wish to be sure that I can reach any state. You can assume $\theta, \phi$ to be some real number.

Comment: What does it mean to "reach any unit vector" ?

Comment: @123 by "reach any unit vector" I mean that, by applying a combination of matrices to the original vector state, I can get as a result any unit vector in $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Comment: You need to check if your overall linear transformation (combination of matricies) applied to the vector results in standard basis of $\Bbb C^4$. Is $\theta, \phi$ constant ?

Comment: @123 $\theta, \phi$ can be varied depending on the beamsplitter/phaseshifter in use (these are standard optical components). Are you saying that if I multiply both matrices together and I get the basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ (what exactly does that mean?) then I can reach any unit vector?

Comment: Any vector in a vector space can be represented uniquely represented by linear combination of its basis vectors. In $\Bbb C^4$ among infinitely bases, the vectors $(1,0,0,0)^T,(0,1,0,0)^T,(0,0,1,0)^T ,(0,0,0,1)^T$ are called standard basis. If you can "reach" these vectors you "reach" any vector in $\Bbb C^4$ that includes unit vectors.

Comment: @123 okay, that makes sense. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: No because I did not understand your question. If $A$ and $B$ are your matrices then what's valid combination of these ? Is any random combination of $A$ and $B$ allowed ?

Comment: @123 I believe so, yes. Perhaps it'll help to provide some context for this: I'm thinking in the context of applying different operations to a photon. I can apply these operations in any order, but I wish to be sure that I can reach any state.

Comment: Ok, if I understand properly, you want to prove that for fixed $\theta,\phi$ some combination of $A$ and $B$ (times your vector) will get you all the vectors in $\Bbb C^4$ right ?

Comment: @123 Basically. The values $\theta,\phi$ can be changed; these are basically specific characteristics of those operations I'm thinking of, dependent on the experimental setup. I also don't care about any vectors which are not unit vectors.

Comment: No, that is causing the problem, say my combination of matrices is $AB$, then can I tweak $\theta, \phi$ such that I get $AB \vec v = (1,0,0,0)^T$ ?

Comment: @123 oh...I think I see what you mean. You couldn't tweak them to anything you wanted, because there are limits to what can be built, but devices with different values of $\theta, \phi$ can be built. I guess maybe it'd make more sense to pretend they were fixed or something...

Comment: Ok from mathematically standpoint, we don't have to care about $\phi, \theta$, we assume it to be some real number, right ?

Comment: @123 yeah. Sorry that it took me so long to give you the info you wanted =)

Comment: Nah no problem. Can you edit this in the question ?

Comment: @123 edited in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68038/discussion-between-123-and-heather).